# Counting values in pandas dataframe using lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a list of years in a pandas data frame. I want to filter them using a lambda function, which I am trying to pass using count method. For me, using lambda is the most convenient way, I would prefer a solution that involves lambda.

```
print df['year_built'][:5]
print df['year_built'].count(lambda x: len(x) == 4)
```

```
0    1981
1    1980
2    1935
3    2007
4    1994
Name: year_built, dtype: object

AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'levels'
```

What is the optimal way to do this using lambda and without it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `count` doesn't even take a callable object. Are you trying to count the number of elements of length 4?

Comment: @gmds yes, I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use list comprehension.

```
[x for x in df['year_built'] if len(x) == 4]
```

Comment: this looks like the most elegant way! Could you let me know why the lambda wasn't working?

Comment: Iterating over large datasets by hand is forbidden in data science.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this, I think, is (assuming `year_built` is a column of `object` type and contains strings:

```
df.loc[df['year_built'].str.len() == 4, 'year_built']
```

If it doesn't:

```
df.loc[(1000 <= df['year_built']) & (df['year_built'] < 9999), 'year_built']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume `year_build` is column of string. Below will give you count of rows where len = 4

```
  year_build
0       1981
1       1980
2       1935
3       2007
4       1994
5         67
6         89

In [149]: (df['year_build'].str.len() == 4).sum()
Out[149]: 5
```